# How does Disqus store the comments?

Tags: data-structures, disqus

I am just curious, how does Disqus store the comments. I mean, if I had to build some comment system for blog, I would create a table for comments and one for blog posts. Then I would create a one-to-many relationship between them so that each blog post would have many comments.

This is fine when we have one type of entity to comment on. But if we want to have comments on different types of entities like pages, blog posts, images, videos, and etc, Things get a little bit tricky. I can't think of a clean way to use something like the above solution.

One solution I can think of, is to use the URI of the page as a key to distinguish the comments.

So, what do you think? What do you think about Disqus? Any solutions?

(P.S: If you are going to down vote, please let me know the reason, in a comment).